# Equivalent of REST for E-Mail

Tags: rest, email, http

REST is made for HTTP. Is there a equivalent of REST for E-Mail (SMTP, POP3 or IMAP)?

I'm thinking of something where the request is send by mail and the response also comes as mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [Message Broker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker) / [Message Oriented Middleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Oriented_Middleware) / Message Queueing solution that is supporting SMTP. Even this soulution have 'Message' in there name they don't have anything to do with email. They concentrate on solutions to get a message for sure (safe and secure) from one server to another.

What came direct to my mind was Apache ActiveMQ and I search if it can work with SMTP together and I found [Apache Camel - Mail Component](http://camel.apache.org/mail.html). Form APache Camel Homepage:

> Camel empowers you to define routing and mediation rules in a variety of domain-specific languages, including a Java-based Fluent API, Spring or Blueprint XML Configuration files, and a Scala DSL. This means you get smart completion of routing rules in your IDE, whether in a Java, Scala or XML editor.

I hope this helps to find the answer.